# Compile/typeset Latex in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: latex, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to compile/typeset Latex files from the ipython/jupyter text editor? I would like to be able to edit the file and then download a pdf of the updated output.

E.g. I currently store my CV (CV.tex) on the same server that I run jupyter. After editing the file in Jupyter's web based text editor, I would like to run "pdflatex CV.tex" and compile it to a pdf in that same directory. I currently get around this by creating a notebook with a single cell and

```
%%bash
pdflatex CV.tex
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that would be great as well, but I don't think there is a way to write up an entire document on Jupyter. They do however provide a nifty option for inserting blocks of LaTeX in-between your code cells.

Use the markdown option for the cell and you can now typeset text or math using either option (a) for text, or option (b) for inline mathematics:
a) %%latex
b) $ ... $

PS. we all know that option (a) should have been %%LaTeX, but it is what it is.

PPS. this is my first answer to a question on Stack Overflow.

So I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your answer will work only for LaTeX in the jupyter notebook.

However, it will not work in a notebook that contains both LaTeX and python code and all the figures that were created by the python code if you run:

```
jupyter   nbconvert my_notebook.ipynb --to  pdf
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).